# Riverpod for flutter doesn't work after copy of project

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I had a Flutter project with an app already being developed on local, and copied the files to a new folder so I use it as a repository for Git.
After doing the "pubspec get packages" everything is all right except from some lines that are related to Riverpod. If I return to the old folder the exact same code work perfectly finde so I guess I have to do something more. Here there is an example:

```
final nombreJuegoTextFieldProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) {
  return '';
});
void updateNombreJuegoTextField(BuildContext context, String nombre) {
  context.read(nombreJuegoTextFieldProvider).state = nombre;
}
```

And the problem showed is:

```
The method 'read' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'read'.
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `ref.read` ? where `ref` is a `WidgetRef` not `BuildContext` ? Please provide a mor complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't copied all the files to the new folder. Repeat copying. This should include all directories and files from the previous version.

Then run two commands:

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

In this example of the code presented, the provider's state can be accessed using `ref`:

```dart
ref.read(nombreJuegoTextFieldProvider).state = nombre;
```

Answer (score 2):

`context.read` is from Provider package

For riverpod, you need to use `ref.read`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

-> deleting .gitignore files
-> Run flutter clean project

or maybe the paths got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I just repeated the same process again and everything works, I guess the copy paste I did the first time had an error I don't know.